# how can i mouseover on text instead of click

Tags: jquery

I'm working on the mega drop menu please visit the site at  [bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/mega-menu-with-carousel-for-stores),
as you can see when click it will show mega menu, my question is that how can I mouse over instead of click !

many thanks.

Alidad

Comment: :hover (css) or .hover() (jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.dropdown.mega-dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu{
  display:block;
  }
```

you overwrite css class style like this, you can get submenu on hover.

Comment: hi, i missing something, after i used that code, the arrow is missing. The top arrow on mega drop down is missing. any idea why!

Comment: down arrow or triangle?

Answer (score 0):

example from:

http://help.dottoro.com/ljudwitu.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnMouseIn (elem) {
        elem.style.border = "2px solid blue";
    }
    function OnMouseOut (elem) {
        elem.style.border = "";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:#d0f0a0; width:200px" 
        onmouseover="OnMouseIn (this)" onmouseout="OnMouseOut (this)">
    Move your mouse pointer into and out of this element!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dropdown.mega-dropdown:hover>.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 285px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.dropdown.mega-dropdown:hover>.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 19px solid transparent;
    border-left: 19px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    left: 283px;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

also add this style...

Comment: Thanks so much but still not working, the triangle showing fine, but staying same place no matter which link to mouse over.  why triangle show stay same area no matter which mouseover!